# Responsive CSS Issue

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

Wow I am really struggling.

I have created responsive themes for many many sites but can't get it to work on my own!

The dev version of the site is at [Development Site](http://dev.tailoredinternetmarketing.com/) and the CSS for the phone part of the stylesheet is below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
* {
    float: none!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}
#container, #home-boxes, #header, #home-scroller, #main-nav, #main-footer, #content, #sidebar  {
    width: 100%!important;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: none;    
}
.wrapper {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    width: auto;
}
#home-scroller h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
#home-scroller h1 span {
    font-size: 30px;
}
#home-scroller p.home-price {
    font-size: 30px;
}
#home-scroller a.button, #home-scroller a.buttonalt {
    display: block; 
}
#home-scroller p.bottom {
    position: inherit;  
}
ol.dots { display: none; }
#home-scroller li {
    width: 100%;
}
#main-nav {
    float:none;
}
#home-boxes-inner .home-box, .footer-box {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#logo {
    float: none;
}
}
```

As you can see if you visit the site on a mobile it's not even close to being anywhere near correct.

Does anyone have any pointers on where I should be looking?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Something like https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile-first+responsive+design&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=12SPU425LMXP8gfKh4DwDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard coded html-width conflicts with this nice meta setting :

```
html {
   min-width: 1060px; /* hard coded width for large screens */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   /* new: fit viewport to small device screen */
   min-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: You sir(/madam) are a god!

Sometimes you just can't see what's in front of your eyes when you're so deep in a project :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your meta width tag from

```
<meta wisth...
```

To

```
<meta width...
```

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo, I took it out to test and readded for this question.

Still the same.